# Is the azurerm_client_config data provider broken in TF 0.12.13?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I've just upgraded a TF project from 0.11.14 to 0.12.13.  I also upgraded to the latest Azure provider, v 1.36.0.  Now the azurerm_client_config data provider isn't working.  It's a very simple data provider:
   data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

That one line of code returns "Error: Error getting authenticated object ID: Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1."

I'm initializing the Azure provider using environment variables, including authentication via a service principal with Owner access to my subscription.  It was previously a Contributor but I added the Owner role to see if that would fix it.  No such luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3814